# Query Dates by Min Max of Percentage

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, max, google-query-language

I have two columns. Column A contains 3 dates. Column B contains 3 percentage values. What is the formula then to find the date for the highest vs. the date for the lowest percentage?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-formula/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max:

```
=SORTN(A:A; 1; 0; B:B; 0)
```

min:

```
=SORTN(A:A; 1; 0; B:B; 1)
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A where B ="&MIN(B:B), )
```

and

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A where B ="&MAX(B:B), )
```

[image]

Comment: What if there are two dates with the same Max Percentage?

Comment: @HelpMePlease can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-YW7prEz2rkCKangks2CeDK2spCidGQa8hJJhXWmGiI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @HelpMePlease answer updated